# What is the average value of current in uncontrolled rectifiers with rl Load

Tags: current, impedance, rectifier, full-bridge, half-bridge

I am trying to calculate the average value of a current in single phase rectifier half wave and in the full wave with RL Load.

[image: Uncontrolled half wave rectifier with RL load]

The thing that I am finding interesting is that in all the tutorials and books I find that even that the circuit has a resistance and inductance insted of calculating the average value of current by dividing by circuit impedance Z like this :

i<sub>avg</sub> = u/Z where z = √(R<sup>2</sup> + (Lω)<sup>2</sup>) they use only the value of the resistance and they calculate i<sub>avg</sub> = u/R.

The same thing happens with full wave rectifier and with the controlled and with the uncontrolled.

I tried to find the equation of current and calculate the average value of current using the integral and I find the result u/R so is this the reason? Should I do the same process for all the other rectifiers where finding the equation of the current can be little bit more hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The thing that I am finding interesting is that in all the tutorials
> and books I find that even that the circuit has a resistance and
> inductance insted of calculating the average value of current by
> dividing by circuit impedance Z like this : iavg = u/Z where z = √(R² + (Lω)²) they use only the value of the resistance and they calculate iavg = u/R.*

The average value of current is a **DC value** hence, in your formula Lω becomes zero and, you are left with z = √(R²) = R.

The easy way to find average current is average voltage divided by R. This applies to half-wave and full-wave (or bridge) rectification. [This table](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264650/rectifiers-parameters) should help: -

[image]

And, the reason why this works when you have an inductor is because the average voltage across the inductor must be zero (or you get unfeasibly large currents after a reasonably short time period). So, if the average voltage from the rectifier is (say) \$V_{AVG}\$ then the average voltage on the resistor side of the inductor must also be \$V_{AVG}\$ hence, the average current into the resistor is \$V_{AVG}\$ divided by \$R\$.

Answer (score 1):

I put some real values on your circuit and I simulated it to demonstrate that things are a bit more complicated than looking in a table will tell you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpC3e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What makes this circuit, as drawn, problematic is that the average voltage at the hot end of L1 is *not* a half-wave rectified voltage.  The reason that it is not is because while the diode has a low voltage drop when it is in forward conduction, it is at a high impedance while it is reverse biased and not conducting.

This changing impedance at the cathode of D1 means that when the diode is reverse biased the "hot" end of L1 is held at the same voltage as the cold end.

Simulate the circuit to see what I mean -- in this case, the voltage "resistorV" bumps up to a bit over 2V then back to zero, while the junction of D1 and L1 oscillates well above *and below* ground.

If you want a half-wave rectified, choke-filtered supply, you need an additional diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw4lF5.png)</sup>

If you simulate *this* circuit, you will see R1 acquiring a significant DC bias, and you will see the junction of the two diodes and L1 taking on a good-looking half-wave rectified waveform.